# TypeORM: Cannot read property 'inverseJoinColumns' of undefined when saving

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, entity, typeorm

The use case: If a user is not yet created in the db, create it - if the user already exists, update it.

The logic for this works. As TypeORM's `.save()` updates entities or updates them when not available, I want to use this method.

My problem: Creating works but not updating. It throws this error from the `RelationIdLoader` when doing this:

```
this.userRepository.save(user); // user = newly created or updated entity
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'inverseJoinColumns' of undefined

The only difference between the updated and the created one is that the updated one has an `id` property, which is a uuid/string.

## Update

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') public id: string;

... // some columns without relations

@OneToMany(type => Finding, finding => finding.reporter)
public reportedFindings: Finding[];

@OneToMany(type => Finding, finding => finding.responsible)
public responsibleFindings: Finding[];

@ManyToMany(type => DataCenter)
public dataCenterResponsiblities: DataCenter[];

@ManyToMany(type => Finding)
public informedFindings: Finding[];
```

Comment: show your entities, must probably you setup entity relations wrongly

Comment: @pleerock Just did so. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: if you use `@ManyToMany` you must put `@JoinTable` decorator as well (only on owning side, since you have a one-way-relation you put it only here).

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks alot for this great library @pleerock. There's another question coming in shortly. :)

Comment: please find a time to answer on your own question and accept it to improve user experience on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pleerock noted, all `@ManyToMany` have to include the `@JoinTable` decorator on the owning side.

So the concrete solution to my actual problem is the following:

```
@ManyToMany(type => DataCenter)
@JoinTable()
public dataCenterResponsiblities: DataCenter[];

@JoinTable()
@ManyToMany(type => Finding)
public informedFindings: Finding[];
```

[This is actually well described in the docs.](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md)

Comment: The owning side means the side which updates the relation ?

Comment: @Nicu example: A finding is assigned to a datacenter by the datacenter‘s id. So the datacenter „owns“ findings[].